# How to properly join LF character in an array?

Tags: ruby

Basic question.

Instead of adding '\n' between the elements:

```
>> puts "#{[1, 2, 3].join('\n')}"
1\n2\n3
```

I need to actually add the line feed character, so the output I expect when printing it would be:

1

2

3

What's the best way to do that in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double quotes.

```
puts "#{[1, 2, 3].join("\n")}"
```

Note that you don't have to escape the double quotes because they're within the `{}` of a substitution, and thus will not be treated as delimiters for the outer string.

However, you also don't even need the `#{}` wrapper if that's all your doing - the following will work fine:

```
puts [1,2,3].join("\n")
```

Comment: @Dav, before I saw you answer I tested mine... and realized this. I guess I never tried it before, I only use substitution for simple variables or `variable.method` syntax. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Escaped characters can only be used in double quoted strings:

```
puts "#{[1, 2, 3].join("\n")}"
```

But since all you output is this one statement, I wouldn't quote the `join` statement:

```
puts [1, 2, 3].join("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that join only adds line feeds between the lines.  It will not add a line-feed to the end of the last line.  If you need every line to end with a line-feed, then:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

lines = %w(one two three)
s = lines.collect do |line|
  line + "\n"
end.join
p s        # => "one\ntwo\nthree\n"
print s    # => one
           # => two
           # => three
```

Comment: Or [1, 2, 3].join("\n")+"\n" :)

Comment: Indeed.  One is terser, one does not duplicate the "\n".  Which is preferred may be a good barometer of how a developer measures the "R" in "DRY".

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't interpret escape sequences in single-quoted strings.

You want to use double-quotes:

```
puts "#{[1, 2, 3].join(\"\n\")}"
```

NB: My syntax might be bad - I'm not a Ruby programmer.